# not all code paths return a value while using try, catch and finally

Tags: c#, .net

When I execute the following function, I get an error:

> "Error 'Excel1.WebServiceFunctions.CreateMyTask()': 
>   not all code paths return a value

My Code:

```
public int CreateMyTask()
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invoking CreateTask method");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        m_taskID = taskClient.CreateTask(m_tInstance);
        Console.WriteLine("Task create successfully:ID=" + m_taskID.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        return m_taskID;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An exception has occured. Please check the Excel sheet for more info" + ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Any idea on how I can go behind this? I did a bit of googling but I am not able to zero in exactly

Comment: In the `finally` block add `return 0;` and see if it works.

Comment: What do you want to be returned if there's an exception?

Comment: @MatthewRz control cannot leave the body of a finally clause..i get this error if i put return 0;

Comment: If an exception occurs the `catch` handler will get executed, then the `finally` block and then ...? You are missing another `return` statement, either in the `catch` block or outside the `try/catch/finally` construct.

Comment: @MatthewRz if from finally block he returns value 0, then it'll overwrite the actusal return value of the method.

Comment: @MegaMind Yeah, I just realized that.

Comment: Note that you almost never need to `GC.Collect()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Reason**

Consider this scenario.

An error occurs in code line before return line in try block. Then it will go in catch show messagebox and then in finally and then return what????? It has to return something cause method return type is int.

**Solution**

Do this

```
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
    return m_taskID;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Return 0 or any other int value from catch block, it'll fix this. In your calling method you must understand that int value as an exception.

Answer (score 2):

If there is an error in your code, it will jump to the catch block and never hit your return. You need to put the return outside the try catch block.

```
public int CreateMyTask()
{
    int value = -1;

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invoking CreateTask method");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        m_taskID = taskClient.CreateTask(m_tInstance);
        Console.WriteLine("Task create successfully:ID=" + m_taskID.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        value = m_taskID;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An exception has occured. Please check the Excel sheet for more info" + ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Depending on where and how `m_taskID` is declared, your code might give several kinds of compile-time errors.

Comment: I just updated that for clarity. The OP didnt show where it was declared initially so I wasnt sure how to handle it.

Comment: IMO that's harder to read than having two return statements (at the end of the `try` and `catch` blocks)

Answer (score 1):

write a `return -1` in the catch part which you can catch from the calling method.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily fixed by using a return value.

```
public int CreateMyTask()
{

    int returnValue = -1;       

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invoking CreateTask method");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        m_taskID = taskClient.CreateTask(m_tInstance);
        Console.WriteLine("Task create successfully:ID=" + m_taskID.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        returnValue = m_taskID;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An exception has occured. Please check the Excel sheet for more info" + ex);
        returnValue = -1;  // Shouldn't be necessary but the compiler likes it
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return an `int` when things go wrong.

Your current implementation doesn't return and `int` when an exception is thrown.

```
catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An exception has occured. Please check the Excel sheet for more info" + ex);
                return someDefautOrErrorValue; // <- add return statement here
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();   
            }
            return someDefautOrErrorValue; // <- or alternately here.
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The message "not all code paths return a value" is pretty clear: you declared the method to return something, so every possible path through the code should end in a `return` of an appropriate value. With one exception (nu pun intended): the code path can also end on an exception.

One path through your code is the one without any exceptions. The code then gets to the last statement in the `try` block, which is a `return` - fine.

What now if an exception occurred? The control passed to the `catch` block and nothing gets returned! That is what the compiler complains about. So either throw an exception or return "something". Note that that "something" should tell the caller of this method that "something went wrong".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is pretty straight forward - not all code paths will lead to a return. Think, for example, if an error arises in Console.WriteLine in the try clause, nothing will be returned, since the try clause ends as soon as an error is found, and continues at the catch.

To overcome the issue, you can either add a return in the catch{} clause, such that a return is going to be sent if there is an error:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("An exception has occured. Please check the Excel sheet for more info" + ex);
    return -1;
}
```

You can use any return for the error really. Convention uses -1, since you usually don't get that as a return from the main clause.

or, you can add the return for both in the finally / outside the whole clause, as then all calls to the code will return a value.

Hope to have helped!